# I want the loop to restart itself while keeping the int numbers when it adds one to common weapons

Tags: java, save, reset

There is a Backpack system using println to ++ the integers but it doesn't save and the Math.random() stays the same every time and does not reset either.

I want the whole loop to restart but saving the While loop where the backpack is.
`your text`

```
 // weapon draw system
        double HighLow = (Math.random() * 101);
        String Common = "You found a Common Sword!";
        String Rare = "You found a Rare Sword!";
        String Epic = "You found a Epic Sword!";
        String Legendary = "You found a Legendary Sword!";
        String Exotic = "You found a Exotic Sword!";
        String Unique = "You found a Unique Sword!";
        int common = 0;
        int rare = 0;
        int epic = 0;
        int legendary = 0;
        int exotic = 0;
        int unique = 0;

        //picking the weapon with random numbers
        //i want this part to reset and pick another weapon while saving the backpack part
        do {
            System.out.println(HighLow);
            if (HighLow <= 60) {
                System.out.println(Common);
                common++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 80) {
                System.out.println(Rare);
                rare++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 90) {
                System.out.println(Epic);
                epic++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 95) {
                System.out.println(Legendary);
                legendary++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 99) {
                System.out.println(Exotic);
                exotic++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow >= 99.9) {
                System.out.println(Unique);
                unique++;
                break;
            }
            //the backpack system i want it to save
        } while (common < 20);
        {
            System.out.println("Backpack");
            System.out.println(common + " Common Weapons");
            System.out.println(rare + " Rare Weapons");
            System.out.println(epic + " Epic Weapons");
            System.out.println(legendary + " Legendary Weapons");
            System.out.println(exotic + " Exotic Weapons");
            System.out.println(unique + " Unique Weapons");
        }
```

Comment: If you want the `do-while` part to be repeated, you'll need to encapsulate that inside of another loop. If you want your "backpack" to be saved, then don't reset any of the integers you've defined at the top.

Comment: @fireshadow52 how do i just not reset the int any of the integers?

Comment: *"but it doesn't save"* - What "doesn't save"?  Please be specific.  *"the Math.random() stays the same every time"* - The code shown only ever generates a random number once.  Are you saying it generates the same random number every time you execute your application?  Please clarify.

Comment: @David sorry pretty new to this. I want the Math.random() to generate a new number every time it runs again but i cant seam to get it to loop itself and generate a new number, so once it starts it stays the same number. The backpack is made with integers but those integers reset every time rather then staying the same number when +1 is added to it, it is suppose to generate a new number every time and giving a weapon based off that number and add it to the backpack.

Comment: @Gaming_Cruizer: *"generate a new number every time it runs again"* - Again, it only runs **once** in the code shown.  Where/when/how are you running it again?  *"i cant seam to get it to loop itself"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  Do you mean that you want to generate a random number within each iteration of your `do/while` loop?  If so then you'd put that code in that loop, just like any other code that you want to be in that loop.  *"but those integers reset every time"* - Define "every time".  It sounds like there's more to this than what you're showing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

*How do I just not reset the int any of the integers?*

I'm assuming your "backpack" is composed of the following values:

```
        int common = 0;
        int rare = 0;
        int epic = 0;
        int legendary = 0;
        int exotic = 0;
        int unique = 0;
```

What I meant in my original comment was that if you encapsulate the `do-while` loop in another loop, don't set the backpack values equal to 0 again. For instance:

```
...
    while (some_condition) {
        // don't reset backpack values
        do {
            HighLow = Math.random() * 101;
            System.out.println(HighLow);
            if (HighLow <= 60) {
                System.out.println(Common);
                common++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 80) {
                System.out.println(Rare);
                rare++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 90) {
                System.out.println(Epic);
                epic++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 95) {
                System.out.println(Legendary);
                legendary++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow <= 99) {
                System.out.println(Exotic);
                exotic++;
                break;
            } else if (HighLow >= 99.9) {
                System.out.println(Unique);
                unique++;
                break;
            }
            //the backpack system i want it to save
        } while (common < 20);
    }
```

That way, your "backpack" item counts are "saved" in between `do-while` executions.